# How can I create a ListView in JavaFX from an ArrayList of type Object?

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist, scenebuilder

I'm trying to create a March Madness 2019 generator in JavaFX/SceneBuilder. I've never created a GUI before.

I created a new JavaFX project with the files: `Main.java`,`Sample.fxml`, `Team.java` and `Controller.java`.

The `Main` class contains ArrayLists of type Team for each round. As mentioned in the comments below, I've incorrectly placed code in the main method, so any suggestions on where to place it would be greatly appreciated. I've seen tutorials where a method initializes and fills an ArrayList so please let me know if I should do that.

My main question is: how can I display all the teams' names in the first round in a ListView? I've created a method called `generateData()` but when I run my program, it doesn't display anything.

Here is all my code: https://pastebin.com/m3WnNiLW

Comment: Uh... could you please minimize it? (Create [MCVE]) :)

Comment: Well - your code does sucessfully create a `ListView` containing the names. You just don't use it anywhere, let alone add it to a scene. BTW: Why does your `Team` class extend your `Application` class?

Comment: How can I add the list view to a scene? I extended the Main class in the Team class because I had some errors early on but I’ll remove it now

Comment: I have been through a ton of tutorials and only in rare cases have I seen code in the `public static void main(String[] args) {}` other than `launch(args);`. Where did you learn that?

Comment: I didn't learn that anywhere. I originally had something in the post asking whether that was the correct place to put my ArrayList's, but I removed it to make the post more concise. There's still part of that in the post. Since people keep asking for clarification, I've never made a GUI before or used JavaFX so I don't know what I'm doing